# ie8 scroll using arrows in flash

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-8, scroll

i have a problem with a game in flash , this game using up and down arrows, for some reason, when i click the game , the web page scrolls too, how can i fix it ? , i use this cheat in javascript but didn't work:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
       var k = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
       if(k >= 37 && k <= 40) {

           return false;
       }
   }
```

Also ,this game is loading trought another flash that embeds an iframe loading the flash game.

Thanks.

Sebastian.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the wmode attribute to a solid colour (i.e. the same colour as your page background).

Comment: Further my comment above, wmode transaprent seems to cause Flash movies to lose focus when using the arrow keys hence why I mention try setting wmode to a solid colour. The only issue is by not having wmode transparent the Flash movie may appear above other items on your page

Comment: Thanks dude , 7 years later i just entered to this account today !! jaja